# Using IPN on PayPal

Tags: php, curl, mysqli, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've created a checkout system using PayPal. I'm using some code for the IPN that I got from GitHub, and I've added a piece of code to mark the item as sold in the inventory, which is stored in the website's MySQL database.

I have tested the code, and I have found that it carries out the CURL and a message is received at PayPal's end, but the code to update the database wasn't being executed. To test that the code to update the database worked, I moved it to before when the CURL is carried out. When I did this, the code ran, and the database was updated. So, there must be an issue that stops the code when the CURL is executed.

This is the entire code from the page that PayPal sends the IPN to.

```
<?php 
// STEP 1: read POST data 
// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST. 
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.  
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data); 
$myPost = array(); 
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) { 
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval); 
  if (count($keyval) == 2) {$myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);}
} 
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate' 
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; 
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) { 
  $get_magic_quotes_exists = true; 
}  
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {         
  if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {  
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  
  } else { 
    $value = urlencode($value); 
  } 
  $req .= "&$key=$value"; 
} 

// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate 
$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close')); 

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates, 
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set  
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below: 
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'); 
if(!($res = curl_exec($ch))) { 
  error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data"); 
  curl_close($ch); 
  exit; 
} 

// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly 
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) { 
  // The IPN is verified, process it: 
  // check whether the payment_status is Completed 
  // check that txn_id has not been previously processed 
  // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email 
  // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct 
  // process the notification 

  // assign posted variables to local variables 
  $item_number = $_POST['item_number']; 
  $item_name = $_POST['item_name']; 
  $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status']; 
  $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross']; 
  $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency']; 
  $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id']; 
  $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email']; 
  $payer_email = $_POST['payer'];
  include('sql.php');
  mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
  $sql = "UPDATE inventory SET sold='1' WHERE code='".$item_number."'";
  if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
      echo $key." = ". $value."<br>"; 
    }
  }else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
  }
  mysqli_close($mysqli);

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) { 
  // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation 
  echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>"; 
} 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Did that code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I literally just did this two weeks ago. Such a pain in the butt. Here's what I used:

```
function connectAPI($data, $location){

    $getData = array();
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $getData[] = urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
    }
    $location = $location . '?'.implode('&', $getData);

    $ch = curl_init($location);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $return['status'] = $status;
    $return['response'] = $response;

    return $return;
}

$input = $_POST;
$headers = getallheaders();
$location = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$response = array('cmd'=>'_notify-validate');
$jsondata = $response + $input;
$resend = connectAPI($jsondata, $location);

if($resend['response'] === 'VERIFIED'){

    // --- Do what you need to do.

}

echo $resend['response'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test the code yet, because PayPal has suddenly decided the account is verified. Thanks for the code. I'll test it when PayPal decides to behave.

Comment: Cool. Let me know.

Comment: So far, the code has worked in terms of completing the IPN handshake, but it isn't executing my code between 'if($resend['response'] === 'VERIFIED'){' and '}'.

Once again, after testing for a while, PayPal has started saying, 'We're sorry. We can't complete your purchase at this time.' so I'm not sure if I can continue to fiddle with the code today.

Comment: Do you know what $resend['response'] was?

Comment: No. The next thing I was going to try was capturing it to make sure it was coming back as 'VERIFIED' or if it was something else, but PayPal started giving the 'we can't complete you purchase' message. I will try that when I am able to actually put an order through.

Comment: I just tested it. It's returning nothing.

Comment: I checked my host and found that there's a firewall, which disables outgoing connections. I disabled it, and it worked. I did have to modify the code slightly, though, because it wasn't passing the variables back from the function. I just took the code out of the function and put it inline. It works.

Thanks for your help.